# Getting one Element of a JButton in Java

Tags: java, netbeans

I was working on a mineSweeper game when I ran into an issue while trying to flag squares. I'm using the code

```
if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                int clickedTile = e.getButton();
                bombNum.setText(""+userMineNum); 
                //flagTile(clickedTile);
            }
```

To try and access the number of the JButton. However, this always results in the value of clickedTile being 3 (it's an array of JButtons so that's impossible more than once). Anyway, I looked into e.getSource(), which gets the whole object, and if I were to print it out for an object it'd be:

```
javax.swing.JButton[,221,124,44x31,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=,flags=288,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=resources/0.png,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],paintBorder=false,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text= ,defaultCapable=true]
```

With the important field being "text" (which i can later change, however it's blank right now). I want to know how to access it so i can save its value to set the flag in the right location.

```
e.getSource().text
```

Doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `e.getButton()` indicates which button of the mouse is being clicked. In your case the right one, or number 3.

Other than that, I believe you could get the text of the button doing:

```
((JButton) e.getSource()).getName()
```

or

```
((JButton) e.getSource()).getText()
```

But I'd strongly recommend you to check wether it's a button that's being clicked and not other component.